# How would I capture a "double-click" on a touch-screen device with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-8, touchscreen

I'm working on an application that will be released both for desktop and for mobile devices with touch screens. There is a feature which will require the user to double-click (for desktop).

How do I capture a "double-click" on a touch-screen device? Is that even possible?

Comment: Have you been able to get a single click working on a touch screen device using JavaFX?  If so, did you use the mouse event `setOnMouseClicked`?

Comment: I was working under the presumption it had something to do with the Touch series of options in the Code section on the JavaFX Scene Builder. Was I mistaken? Will the mouse "click" events be captured just the same? Also, I haven't yet entered that far in. I'm pretty much just getting started (both with the project and with JavaFX), but before I fumble around wasting precious time I was hoping to find something before I reached that point.

Comment: I don't think it's a waste of ***precious*** time by adding a button with an event to an application and testing it.  I would do it if I had a touch screen computer right now.

Comment: so would i, believe me. I don't have any touch-screen apparatus except for my smart phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a solution by now.

But this is how I did it,

I used the `MousePressed` event with the condition `MouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2`.